# Mango::BSON::ObjectID is not getting installed in perl5.36.0 using cpan

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I switched from Perl 5.30 to Perl 5.36 and using Mojolicious 8.33. I tried installing Mango::BSON::ObjectID using CPAN.

```
cpan Mango::BSON::ObjectID
```

But it was throwing errors.

```
Test Summary Report

t/bson.t  (Wstat: 256 Tests: 182 Failed: 1)
Failed test: 106
Non-zero exit status: 1
Files-13, Tests=205, 4 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr 0.01 sys+ 1.89 
 cusr 0.22 csys=2.17 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/13 test programs. 1/205 subtests failed.
make: *** [Makefile:942: test_dynamic] Error 255
ODC/Mango-1.30.tar.gz 
/usr/bin/make test NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan testers results for installing this 
module, try:
reports ODC/Mango-1.38.tar.gz
```

So, I just want to know if Mango is supported in Perl 5.36.0 or not. And if it is not being supported, then what is the alternative to Mango?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: [Test t/bson.t failing (with Mojolicious 8.50?)](https://github.com/oliwer/mango/issues/36)

When you encounter a problem with a module, you can check its repo for known issues. Go to [MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org), search for the module, and go to its page. On the left of the page, there is a list of resources; one of those is "Issues". Follow that and look for your problem.

In this case, the issue has a patch, although the module has not been updated in five years. You can apply the patch yourself though.